# How to read a local text file in the browser?

Tags: javascript, file-io, xmlhttprequest

I’m trying to implemennt a simple text file reader by creating a function that takes in the file’s path and converts each line of text into a char array, but it’s not working.

```
function readTextFile() {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", "testing.txt", true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      var allText = rawFile.responseText;
      document.getElementById("textSection").innerHTML = allText;
    }
  }
  rawFile.send();
}
```

What is going wrong here?

This still doesn’t seem to work after changing the code a little bit from a [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14446447/1) and now it's giving me an `XMLHttpRequest` exception 101.

I’ve tested this on Firefox and it works, but in Google Chrome it just won't work and it keeps giving me an Exception 101. How can I get this to work on not just Firefox, but also on other browsers (especially Chrome)?

Comment: What specifically is happening. Is there nothing in the array? Or just the "wrong" stuff..?

Comment: Are you testing on a local machine? Make sure to test for a `status` of `0` as well as `200`.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney yes I'm testing this on a local machine. I have stored the text file at the same place as the javascripts and html

Answer (score 408, accepted):

JS introduced the Fetch API in 2015, which replaced XMLHttpRequest with a much simpler way to get data from URLs. In this case:

```js
fetch("myText.txt")
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((text) => {
    // do something with "text"
   })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

And since all mordern browsers severely lock down what they can do with direct filesystem access, try not to use `file:///`. Even if you're "just working locally" there are tons of light weight webservers that you can use (including things like running `python -m http.server` or `npx http-server`) so you can load your data using normal http urls.

**original answer**

You need to check for status 0 (as when loading files locally with `XMLHttpRequest`, you don't get a status returned because it's not from a `Webserver`)

```js
function readTextFile(file) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)  {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        console.log(allText);
       }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
```

And specify `file://` in your filename:

```js
readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");
```

Comment: I'm actually working on this on a mac, so would I still be specifying the file://??

Comment: Something like "file:///tmp/my_file"

Comment: Doesn't seem to work I've typed in "file:///User/Danny/Desktop/javascriptWork/testing.txt" but it pops up an alert with nothing in it

Comment: try to put `file:///User/Danny/Desktop/javascriptWork/testing.txt` in your browser's url bar and see if you can see the file..

Comment: got it to work on browser, but still printing nothing on the alert

Comment: are you running you JS in a local html file or on a remote server ?

Comment: it's all local. all in one folder nothing else.

Comment: that's strange... can you use jQuery for that?

Comment: I never used jQuery before, so I have no idea how to do this in jQuery. This is why I was trying to do this all in html/javascript

Comment: This would fit into a jQuery ajax handler with text being received in success.

Comment: it doesn't need to be an absolute path.. this worked for me just fine: readTextFile('Properties/version.txt'); thanks!

Comment: I am facing exact same problem. Not working for me too even if I add file:/// when I am working in my local using no server at all.

Comment: Since we are reading from a webserver, we should have async set to `true`. If this were a simple `local` search then setting async to `false` is ok, but `onreadystatechange` is not needed while it is set to false. Here is the documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: This won't work in Chrome (possiblity other browsers) you will get "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: Does this really work without user interaction? I can't get it to work in chrome (without the user choosing the file).

Comment: How can one return a value from this? I can get the text from the file to show up in an alert, or in console.log, but I can't seem to return it.

      console.log(allText.split("\n"));  //This works

       return allText.split("\n"); //This doesn't (undefined)

Comment: I'm getting a warning that says this is deprecated :/ any recommendations on an alternative method?

Comment: anyone know if this will work in IE 10 and above... or Edge?  It works in firefox

Comment: @RickBurgess You need to run the code in apache server, it works.

Comment: I am getting `Access is denied.`. My browser is IE11. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Didn't work in Chrome. FireFox also threw an error: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated`

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome now. I think generally async (3d parameter in `open()`) should be set to true.

Comment: To all users who need a good answer: `fetch("myText.txt", {mode: "no-cors"}).then(res => res.text()).then(text => doSomethingWithText(text))`

Comment: how is that a good answer index.html:13 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/un/job/plugin_reader/debug. URL scheme "file" is not supported.

Comment: @user151496 maybe because it was answered 7 years ago ?

Comment: What is base path?

Comment: This is really useful! I'm using it with JSZip to move contents of an scss file into a new file within the zip.

Comment: For anyone getting CORS error -- try to run the file on live/development server.  It won't work if you directly open the HTML file in the browser.

Comment: I want to read local image file as dataURL, how can i do that?

Comment: Dany (OP) requested opening a local file not on a server side, so why a reply with a wrong solution to initial question got so many upvotes? Solution simply does not work due to CORS violations. And a comment by @Rick Burgess here highlight this and received 202 upvotes but original  response here didn't receive -202 downvotes?

Comment: The answer was posted Jan 2013 and the comment was posted 3 years later, after the browsers started limiting what the browser can do on the filesystem.

Answer (score 202):

After the introduction of [fetch api](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) in javascript, reading file contents could not be simpler.

**reading a text file**

```
fetch('file.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  // outputs the content of the text file
```

**reading a json file**

```
fetch('file.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonResponse => console.log(jsonResponse))     
   // outputs a javascript object from the parsed json
```

### Update 30/07/2018 (disclaimer):

> This technique works fine in **Firefox**, but it seems like **Chrome**'s `fetch` implementation does not support `file:///` URL scheme at the date of writing this update (tested in Chrome 68).

### Update-2 (disclaimer):

> This technique does not work with **Firefox** above version 68 (Jul 9, 2019) for the same (security) reason as Chrome: `CORS request not HTTP`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp.

Comment: Brilliant! Quoting the Fetch Standard: "provides consistent handling of: URL schemes, Redirects, Cross-origin semantics, CSP, Service workers, Mixed Content, `Referer`". I guess this means goodbye to good ol'FileReaders and HttpRequests (and I won't miss them a bit ;)

Comment: But how can you use the *text* and put it into a string variable for use elsewhere? (I keep on getting 'undefined' no matter what I do to it.)

Comment: @not2qubit fetching a text file is an async operation. You are getting undefined because you are using the variable before the file is completely read. You have to use it inside the promise callback or use something like javascript "async await" operators.

Comment: `Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/path/to/file/file.txt. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

Comment: same here stupid Chrome 68.  I can't believe this is a hot topic, thanks @AbdelazizMokhnache keep us informed. JAK. I just tested File-Save.js, it works, and I want something simple to read the file back (basically save/restore my settings to a file of my choice)

Comment: browser compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Actually it is not possible with Firefox since version 68 (July 2019) to read local file using `fetch` for the same (security) reason as Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp

Comment: If you upload your script with your text file it solves the URL scheme problem. A little bit of an annoying process, but it seems to still be far easier than XMLRequests

Comment: file.uri.strict set to false if you want to read local files inside your project dir

Comment: to enable fetch in chrome - put the files you want to expose in the assets folder (or any equivalent folder)

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 88 but not in Chrome 94.

Answer (score 142):

Visit [Javascripture](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader) ! And go the section **readAsText** and try the example. You will be able to know how the **readAsText** function of **FileReader** works.

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = text;
    console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Links are nice, but you should "always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This example deals with a user-input text file, but I think the question was about a file that's local to the server.

Comment: @S.Kirby As said by the OP in response to a question about if it's run locally or on a remote server: [it's all local. all in one folder nothing else.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file#comment20120579_14446538). Besides, other people (like me) might have the question about how to do it locally.

Comment: This solution automatically reads the content of the selected file which I like it. I wanted to make it to work like on urltodomain.com (in a textarea), but it initially failed because of this: `node.innerText = text;` (the script populated the contents but within the <textarea> tags instead of adding it to the textarea). To make it worked I replaced it to: `node.value = text;`

Answer (score 57):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
var output = document.getElementById("output");


input.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var myFile = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      output.textContent = e.target.result;
    });
    
    reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
  }   
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<hr>
<textarea style="width:500px;height: 400px" id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers this 4 year old question. The OP isn't uploading documents, they are trying to read the text file in the same directory from a path. And if you're going to answer questions this old at least write a short summary of why you think your answer is now better than the others or how the language has changed since the question to warrant a new answer.

Comment: Using my own existing file upload input html - copying the lines from `var reader = new FileReader();` through `reader.readAsBinaryString(..)` - it reads the contents of my text file. Clean, elegant, works like a charm.  Best answer in this thread for me - thanks!

Comment: How to get the file name?

Answer (score 40):

### Modern solution:

Use `fileOrBlob.text()` as follows:

```
<input type="file" onchange="this.files[0].text().then(t => console.log(t))">
```

When user uploads a text file via that input, it will be logged to the console. [Here's a working jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/bobeweyede/edit?html,output).

Here's a more verbose version:

```
<input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this.files[0])">
<script>
  async function loadFile(file) {
    let text = await file.text();
    console.log(text);
  }
</script>
```

Currently (January 2020) this only works in Chrome and Firefox, check here for compatibility if you're reading this in the future: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text

On older browsers, this should work:

```
<input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this.files[0])">
<script>
  async function loadFile(file) {
    let text = await (new Response(file)).text();
    console.log(text);
  }
</script>
```

---

Related: As of September 2020  the new [Native File System API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/) available in Chrome and Edge in case you want permanent read-access (and even write access) to the user-selected file.

Comment: What is the path root?

Comment: You need to create the Blob in the example otherwise this is not useful for people I think.

Answer (score 36):

Yes JS can read local files (see FileReader()) but not automatically: the user has to pass the file or a list of files to the script with an html `<input type="file">`.

Then with JS it is possible to process (example view) the file or the list of files, some of their properties and the file or files content.

What JS cannot do for security reasons is to access automatically (without the user input) to the filesystem of his computer.

To allow JS to access to the local fs automatically is needed to create not an html file with JS inside it but an hta document.

An hta file can contain JS or VBS inside it.

But the hta executable will work on windows systems only.

This is standard browser behavior.

Also Google Chrome worked at the fs API, more info here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 18):

Using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and async function

```
const logFileText = async file => {
    const response = await fetch(file)
    const text = await response.text()
    console.log(text)
}

logFileText('file.txt')
```

Comment: I get 'URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.'

Comment: Perfect solution. It was simple as "logFileText('./test.txt')"

Answer (score 12):

Try creating two functions:

```
function getData(){       //this will read file and send information to other function
       var xmlhttp;

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();               
       }           
       else {               
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");               
       }

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {               
           if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {                   
             var lines = xmlhttp.responseText;    //*here we get all lines from text file*

             intoArray(lines);     *//here we call function with parameter "lines*"                   
           }               
       }

       xmlhttp.open("GET", "motsim1.txt", true);
       xmlhttp.send();    
}

function intoArray (lines) {
   // splitting all text data into array "\n" is splitting data from each new line
   //and saving each new line as each element*

   var lineArr = lines.split('\n'); 

   //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as below
   document.write(lineArr[2]);         
   document.write(lineArr[3]);
}
```

Comment: For what browsers does this work (it seems 6 people tried it :-) )

Answer (score 12):

Probably you already tried it, but type "false" as follows:

```
     rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
```

Answer (score 11):

other example - my reader with FileReader class

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function PreviewText() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadText").files[0]);
            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                document.getElementById("uploadTextValue").value = oFREvent.target.result; 
                document.getElementById("obj").data = oFREvent.target.result;
            };
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#viewSource').click(function ()
            {
                var text = $('#uploadTextValue').val();
                alert(text);
                //here ajax
            });
        });
        </script>
        <object width="100%" height="400" data="" id="obj"></object>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="uploadTextValue" name="uploadTextValue" value="" />
            <input id="uploadText" style="width:120px" type="file" size="10"  onchange="PreviewText();" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="viewSource">Source file</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: File return base64 output

Answer (score 6):

This question may be old but there two main ideas that we need to clarify. Do we want to read the whole file at once? or read it line by line?

#### Teo, I want to get the whole file and process it later.

Okay, that is very easy. We just need to call [`Blob.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) method (remember that this method assumes that the file is encoded as `UTF-8`) and handle the file like this:

```js
const $output = document.getElementById('output')
const $file = document.getElementById('file')
const fetchFile = async e => {
  const [file] = e.target.files
  const text = await file.text()
  $output.textContent = text
}

$file.onchange = fetchFile
```

```html
<input id='file' type='file' accept='text/plain'><br>
<pre id='output'>...</pre>
```

#### What about line by line? Is that possible?.

Yes my young Padawan, that is also possible. We just need to call the  [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#removing_spaces_from_a_string) method to divide the text into an array of lines like this:

```js
const $output = document.getElementById('output')
const $file = document.getElementById('file')
let count
const fetchFile = async e => {
  const [file] = e.target.files
  if (!file) return
  count = 0
  const text = await file.text()
  $output.textContent = text

  const lines = text.split(/\r?\n/gm)
  for (const line of lines) {
    if (line) count++
  }
  console.log({count})
}

$file.onchange = fetchFile
```

```html
<input id='file' type='file' accept='text/plain'><br>
<pre id='output'>...</pre>
```

Comment: @Teocci Good example, I would like to understand how CORS violation policy is not happening in this example?

Comment: The `CORS policy` is a security feature that prevents browsers from making cross-origin requests to other servers.
This code does not violate the CORS policy because the file is being fetched from the local file system, not from a remote server.

Answer (score 5):

This might help,

```
    var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 3):

### Local AJAX calls in Chrome are not supported due to same-origin-policy.

Error message on chrome is like this:
"Cross origin requests are not supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

This means that chrome creates a virtual disk for every domain to keep the files  served by the domain using http/https protocols. Any access to files outside this virtual disk are restricted under same origin policy. AJAX requests and responses happen on http/https, therefore wont work for local files.

Firefox does not put such restriction, therefore your code will work happily on the Firefox. However there are workarounds for chrome too : [see here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/).

Comment: Your "see here" link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

```
function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest(); // XMLHttpRequest (often abbreviated as XHR) is a browser object accessible in JavaScript that provides data in XML, JSON, but also HTML format, or even a simple text using HTTP requests.
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false); // open with method GET the file with the link file ,  false (synchronous)
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4) // readyState = 4: request finished and response is ready
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200) // status 200: "OK"
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText; //  Returns the response data as a string
                console.log(allText); // display text on the console
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null); //Sends the request to the server Used for GET requests with param null
}

readTextFile("text.txt"); //<= Call function ===== don't need "file:///..." just the path
```

**- read file text from javascript** 
**- Console log text from file using javascript** 
 **- Google chrome and mozilla firefox** 
 in my case i have this structure of files : [image]

the console.log result :  
 [image]

Comment: Below is the error showing:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/{myLocalPath}PropertiesFile.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.**

Answer (score 3):

***How to read a local file?***

By using this you will load a file by loadText() then JS will asynchronously wait until the file is read and loaded after that it will execture readText() function allowing you to continue with your normal JS logic (you can also write a try catch block on the loadText() function in the case any error arises) but for this example I keep it at minimal.

```
async function loadText(url) {
    text = await fetch(url);
    //awaits for text.text() prop 
    //and then sends it to readText()
    readText(await text.text());
}

function readText(text){
    //here you can continue with your JS normal logic
    console.log(text);
}

loadText('test.txt');
```

Comment: It seems like you have a case of _function-itis_

Answer (score 2):

Adding to some the above answers, this modified solution worked for me.

```
<input id="file-upload-input" type="file" class="form-control" accept="*" />
```

....

```
let fileInput  = document.getElementById('file-upload-input');
let files = fileInput.files;

//Use createObjectURL, this should address any CORS issues.
let filePath = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
```

....

```
function readTextFile(filePath){
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", filePath , true);
    rawFile.send(null);

    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4){
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0){
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log(allText);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get local file data in js(data.js) load:

```
function loadMyFile(){
    console.log("ut:"+unixTimeSec());
    loadScript("data.js?"+unixTimeSec(), loadParse);
}
function loadParse(){
    var mA_=mSdata.split("\n");
    console.log(mA_.length);
}
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
function hereDoc(f) {
  return f.toString().
      replace(/^[^\/]+\/\*![^\r\n]*[\r\n]*/, "").
      replace(/[\r\n][^\r\n]*\*\/[^\/]+$/, "");
}
function unixTimeSec(){
    return Math.round( (new Date()).getTime()/1000);
}
```

file of data.js like:

```
var mSdata = hereDoc(function() {/*!
17,399
1237,399
BLAHBLAH
BLAHBLAH
155,82
194,376
*/});
```

dynamic unixTime queryString prevents cached.

AJ works in web http://.

Comment: why don't you use the ES6 template literal syntax for multiline strings? (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prompt the user to select a file, then read its contents:

```
// read the contents of a file input
const readInputFile = (inputElement, callback) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    callback(reader.result)
  };
  reader.readAsText(inputElement.files[0]);
};
// create a file input and destroy it after reading it
const openFile = (callback) => {
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  el.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.onchange = () => {readInputFile(el, (data) => {
    callback(data)
    document.body.removeChild(el);
  })}
  el.click();
}
```

Usage:

```
// prompt the user to select a file and read it
openFile(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
                $.ajax({`enter code here`
                    url: "TextFile.txt",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {                 
                            var text = $('#newCheckText').val();
                            var str = data;
                            var str_array = str.split('\n');
                            for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                                // Trim the excess whitespace.
                                str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
                                // Add additional code here, such as:
                                alert(str_array[i]);
                                $('#checkboxes').append('<input type="checkbox"  class="checkBoxClass" /> ' + str_array[i] + '<br />');
                            }
                    }                   
                });
                $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
                    $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" class="checkBoxClass"/> Select All<br />        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This function made for browsers and open file picker dialog and after user selection read file as binary and call callback function with read data:

```
function pickAndReadFile(callback) {
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    el.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.onchange = function (){
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
            document.body.removeChild(el);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(el.files[0]);
    }
    el.click();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
pickAndReadFile(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: You should not be using readAsBinaryString any more...

Answer (score 1):

This thread presently contains a lot of correct yet outdated answers that shouldn't be banned, just removed, for the sake of those looking for an up-to-date solution.

The following is my reply. Its value is conciseness and simplicity. It uses the File object found in the FileList returned by the 'change' event on the Input element. The File is treated as a Blob and turned into plain text using the asynchronous text() function. To use the result of the text() we need to wait for its Promise to be resolved, hence the .then syntax. The console.log(text) statement can be replaced with any function processing the parameter. Tested also on Stackblitz.

```js
document
  .getElementById('fileName')
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    e.target.files[0].text().then((text) => console.log(text));
  });
```

```html
<input id="fileName" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import my library:

```html
<script src="https://www.editeyusercontent.com/preview/1c_hhRGD3bhwOtWwfBD8QofW9rD3T1kbe/code.js?pe=yikuansun2015@gmail.com"></script>
```

then, the function `fetchfile(path)` will return the uploaded file

```html
<script src="https://www.editeyusercontent.com/preview/1c_hhRGD3bhwOtWwfBD8QofW9rD3T1kbe/code.js"></script>
<script>console.log(fetchfile("file.txt"))</script>
```

Please note: on Google Chrome if the HTML code is local, errors will appear, but saving the HTML code and the files online then running the online HTML file works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a local file text through `JavaScript` using chrome, the chrome browser should run with the argument `--allow-file-access-from-files` to allow JavaScript to access local file, then you can read it using `XmlHttpRequest` like the following:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
       var allText = xmlhttp.responseText;          
            }
        };
xmlhttp.open("GET", file, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

I know, I am late at this party. Let me show you what I have got.

This is a **simple reading of text file**

```
var path = "C:\\path\\filename.txt"
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(path , 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('OK: ' + filename);
  console.log(data)
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should *quote* the file path. Moreover, his code uses the DOM library, implying that he meant vanilla JavaScript, not node.js.